# ssl error while trying to access sites with alibaba certificate from aws ec2

Tags: curl, openssl, ssl-certificate

We are trying to fetch data from a alibaba hosted webside from an aws ec2 machine, however the query fails while trying to check certificates.

To reproduce I had Amazon Linux 2 installed on Docker and ran the following commands on terminal:

`curl https://solarsendpro.intelbras.com.br -v`

The result is:

```
*   Trying [::ffff:47.254.41.201]:443...
* Connected to solarsendpro.intelbras.com.br (::ffff:47.254.41.201) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

I tried to download the cert using openssl:

`openssl s_client -connect solarsendpro.intelbras.com.br:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM > solarsend.pem`

Then running again

`curl --cacert solarsend.pem https://solarsendpro.intelbras.com.br -v`

Still the same error. Following other threads about similar issues I found that we can check the cert using openssl verify, then:

`openssl verify solarsend.pem`

Which gives:

```
solarsend.pem: C = CN, ST = \E6\B1\9F\E8\8B\8F\E7\9C\81, L = \E6\97\A0\E9\94\A1\E5\B8\82, O = \E6\97\A0\E9\94\A1\E8\8B\B1\E8\87\BB\E7\A7\91\E6\8A\80\E6\9C\89\E9\99\90\E5\85\AC\E5\8F\B8, CN = *.solarmanpv.com
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I tryied to get the certificate from solarman, using the same approach I did on solarsendpro, but now I get yet another issue checking solarman:

`openssl verify solarman_cert.pem`

And the output:

```
solarman_cert.pem: C = CN, ST = ZheJiang, L = HangZhou, O = "Alibaba (China) Technology Co., Ltd.", CN = *.alicdn.com
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Tryied to download the mozilla certificate bundle, to test again but still no deal. Has anyone ever faced this issue?

Comment: This is not programming or development but **that server is defective** and [fails to provide the required chain/intermediate cert](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=solarsendpro.intelbras.com.br) -- when using SNI; in addition, as with many hosting services, with no SNI it provides a different and wrong (but complete!) cert chain. **Yes many people have encountered defective servers on the Internet.** `openssl s_client >cert` gets only the server/leaf cert, not any CA cert, and certainly not the chain cert the server failed to provide; moreover you appear to be using ...

Comment: ... an out-of-date OpenSSL (below 1.1.1) since it is getting the no-SNI (wrong) cert.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the ansewer, with "not programming or development" you mean the tag is wrong? Fist time here, sry.

The openssl version is 1.0.7, thats what yum gave me, I'll update it later.

About the leaf cert, I understood that the leaf would be enough to validate the page once I have the CA on a cert bundle. However, how can I check for the CAs? The pages work on a "normal" browser with no cert error, is there a way to find the CA on a different computer using command line?

Comment: Anyway @dave_thompson_085 thanks for the answer, I believe I can carry on for now, also https://www.ssllabs.com/ rocks!